# how to use cells value as cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an updating macro. this macro will open other workbooks and then look at the last cell in the column that has data in it and then take a copy of that data and paste it into the original sheet. then I use formulas to work out the cell address by matching the copied data within a range after matching the data it returns a row number and the formula then adds 1 so it will be the next row down and then adds the column letter. the formula looks like this

="R"&MATCH((S1),R1:R500,0)+1

now that I have the cell address of the next cell that needs to be added to the second workbook I an stuck on how to use it. when I am in vba is there a way to reference the value of a cell as a cell reference? in the above example the cell that it returns is "R34" the cell that the formula is located in is Q1 so how can I reference the value of Q1 as the start of my copy range.

my copy sub looks like this

```
        Sub COPYNEWRUNS()

Range("value of Q1:S500").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("LINE 1 PRODUCTION.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("LINE 1 - H").Activate
NextFree = Range("B9:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("B" & NextFree).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

obviously I know that "value of Q1" wont work I just put it there to try an illustrate what I want to achieve. also I am aware that this probably isn't the best way to copy and paste things and I should try to avoid selecting things all the time, but this is the way that I know how to copy and paste in-between other workbooks and it works so that is what I have used to achieve it. I am open to better ways if they are a part of your answer. I am not worried about opening the workbook using vba either as this sub is a test sub. so when it is working the important bits will be getting taken out and put into the larger sub so it can do all of its transferring of data at the same time. just in case you think it might be relevant I will add the main sub below (but this is straying from my original question)

```
Sheet1.Activate
  Workbooks.Open "S:\TEMP TEST\SHEETS\LINE 1 PRODUCTION.xlsm"
  Windows("LINE 1 PRODUCTION.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("BUTTON").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "AFFOC"
    Windows("TOLEDO RUN ORDER.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A3:H500").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("LINE 1 PRODUCTION.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("BUTTON").Activate
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect "AFFOC"
  Workbooks("LINE 1 PRODUCTION.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

this is a part of a larger sub that opens a workbook unprotects a specific sheet copy and paste's data from the original sheet into the second one re-protects the sheet and then saves and closes it. and then moves onto the next sheet.

any advice or help is greatly appreciated. (fyi i am a self taught beginner so sorry if some things go over my head)

Comment: @BigBen please could you provide an example of how to use that? I have only used indirect in formulas and not in vba and I am unsure how to write this in vba (I am googling now but I am struggling to understand how to implement this)

Comment: Actually, skip the `INDIRECT` and do something like `Range(Range("Q1").Value)`.

Comment: @BigBen right okay ill give that a go and let you know if it works, thanks!

Comment: @BigBen I tried this 'Range (Range("Q1").Value): S500 ").Select"' but it automatically adds the set of speech marks at the end of select and comes up with an error that reads invalid use of property and highlights the first range

Comment: `Range(Range("Q1").Value & ":S500").Select`. With the obligatory notice to read [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @BigBen that is coming up with compile error expected: list separator or ). I shall give that post a read, thanks.

Comment: If you're getting a compile error, then you didn't type exactly what is in the previous comment.

Comment: @BigBen right you are, I copied and pasted yours this time and it worked fine I think I left some spaces in that it didn't like that's the only difference I can see anyway ill let you know if this works thanks

Comment: @BigBen that seems to have solved my issue thanks, do you wanna post it as an answer so I can accept it. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("value of Q1:S500").Select
```

would just be

```
Range(Range("Q1").Value & ":S500").Select
```

... but you can rewrite `Sub COPYNEWRUNS()` like this:

```
Sub COPYNEWRUNS()
    Dim targetWb As Workbook
    Set targetWb = Workbooks("LINE 1 PRODUCTION.xlsm")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = targetWb.Worksheets("LINE 1 - H")

    With ws
         Dim nextFree As Long
         nextFree = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
         .Range(.Range("Q1").Value & ":S500").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("B" & nextFree)
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```